Apple libm's sin function
This question is about the implementation of the sin function in Apple's libm C math library, available here.  The main sin function begins on line 736.  In short: when x is small enough so that the nearest float to sin(x) is just x, why does the function do a floating point multiplication whose result is never used then return x, instead of just returning x immediately?
The function uses different methods according to the magnitude xk of the input x. The case I'm interested in is when xk is small enough so that the nearest floating point number to sin(x) is just x, lines 809-829.  I would have guessed that the function would have just done return x in this case.  Here's what it does instead:
/*  Make t0 volatile to force compiler to fetch it at run-time
    rather than optimizing away the multiplication.
*/
static volatile const double t0 = 1/3.;

/*  Get t0 once.  If we wrote "t0*t0", the compiler would load it
    twice, since it is volatile.
*/
const double t1 = t0;

/*  Perform a multiplication and pass it into an assembly construct to
    prevent the compiler from knowing we do not use the result and
    optimizing away the multiplication.
*/
__asm__("" : : "X" (t1*t1));

// Return the floating-point number nearest sine(x), which is x.
return x;

So it creates a new static volatile const double t0 equal to 1/3., another const double t1 with the same value, multiplies t1 by itself in a way it claims the compiler can't optimise out...then returns x. Why does it do this, instead of just returning x at the start?

Wild guess: Perhaps to prevent timing side channel attacks when the function is used in security-relevant contexts?

@Ctx I considered that, but I don't think it can be right.  Aside from anything else, it's just a general purpose math library.


… why does the function do a floating point multiplication whose result is never used then return x…

A floating-point multiply operation has two outputs. One is the numerical value in a floating-point register, and the other is updated flags in the floating-point status bits. At the point in the code you ask about, x is so small that the nearest representable value to sin x is x, so it will be the return value of the function. However, the sine of x is not exactly x, so we would like to raise the inexact flag. Multiplying 1/3. by itself accomplishes that.
You will notice similar care in return x * (1 - 0x1p-53); on line 803. At that point, x is known to be in the subnormal range (it says “denormal,” but “subnormal” is more apt), so x * (1 - 0x1p-53) has, due to rounding, the same value as x. But it also raises the inexact flag if x is nonzero. (And the sine of zero is exact, so it is good not to raise the inexact flag when x is zero.)

I think you've got it, thanks. They include the disclaimer "may or may not raise exact, even if the result is exact" but it seems they do go to some effort to get it right in the two smallest cases.

@MatthewTowers: “They” is I. I wrote that routine.

gosh. Your extensive comments in the source are greatly appreciated.

@EricPostpischil Would calling the internal equivalent of fesetexcept(FE_INEXACT) have accomplished the same thing or is it more subtle than that?

@IanAbbott: I think it is different; fesetexcept only raises the flag. Doing an actual floating-point operation with an inexact result not only raises the flag but triggers an exception if it is enabled for inexact results. In any case, just doing a load of a prepared value and a floating-point multiply instruction is pretty much the fastest way to raise a flag.

I suspect that sin(x) is inexact for all x radian values other than x == +/- 0. I wonder now about the effort to correctly set floating-point status bits for sine_degrees(x) as that has exact rational results at 0 +180°n, +/-30 +180°n. I used to advocate argument reduction of the angle in eighths (360°/8), then a sub-range sine_degrees_45(x) call and then build the answer. I see that to achieve correct floating-point status bits, code may need to first do a reduction of the angle in twelfths (360°/12) (or maybe sixths). Thank-you for the insight into function building.

@chux-ReinstateMonica: Yes, sin has no rational values for arguments (representable values) other than zero. So it will raise inexact except for zero, NaN, and ±∞. (It raises invalid for signaling NaN or ±∞). Saying it may or may not raise inexact even if the result is exact is essentially part of a template specification for most of the math library routines. It is more applicable in, for example, log10, where log10(1e6) may do some calculations and produce the exact result 6, but the intermediate calculations will have raise inexact.

@chux-ReinstateMonica: Since sin always raises inexact for finite arguments other than zero, it is not much use. Anybody calling sin should generally expect inexact to be raised. However, it is hypothetically useful for somebody trying to do exact calculations and calling a library routine they think might be exact but that calls sin internally. Generally, the standard math library routines were treated as things we wanted to respect floating-point semantics reasonably. For people who want speed, there are the vector/SIMD libraries, which may disregard flags and such.
